# How do I know which process (PID) to kill to kill all sleeping processes?

Tags: linux, shell

When I run `top > 1`, I get the following output:

[image]

I was reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/392022/best-way-to-kill-all-child-processes/6481337#6481337) Q&A on Stack Overflow about how to delete sleeping child processes. I think those "child processes" are what I have shown here.

I ran a script which led to listing these sleeping processes. I killed the PID of the script, but noticed all of these sleeping processes still running.

I don't know what the process ID of those processes are, so I don't know how to kill them. Is there a way to know the parent process ID (PID) of the sleeping process?

**How do I determine that PID so that I can kill them?**

Comment: Um, most of the processes in that screenshot should _not_ be killed as they take care of pretty important system functions.

Comment: Also, please, [don't post images of text](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use the following command to find the PID of the process you wish to kill, e.g. 1811 is the child process.

```
ps -f 1811
```

OR

```
ps -o ppid= 1811
```

This will return the parent process id which you can then use.

Comment: Hi thanks for commenting. Right, but how do I get the child PID?! In the screen shot there are several process' running on each core that are sleeping. I'm trying to determine any of their IDs so I can kill them. I tried your answer with the id in the screen ps -f 126918 but that returned an empty set of data ```UID         PID   PPID  C STIME TTY      STAT   TIME CMD```

Comment: This response should help you - 
[https://askubuntu.com/questions/549781/listing-pid-of-sleeping-processes]

Comment: Thanks for the link. I went there and typed their command to generate a list of sleeping PIDs. I then tried your answer and got ```No such process```? For example, the last item on the list generated from the linked answers code snippet was 127566. So I tried ps -f 127566 which returned an empty data row again. Any ideas on where next?

Comment: We can try to see what is blocking the process. Please try this  -
strace -p pid

Comment: ```strace -p 127566
strace: attach: ptrace(PTRACE_ATTACH, ...): No such process```. This PID was taken from the list generated by ```ps h -eo s,pid | awk '{ if ($1 == "S" || $1 == "D") { print $2 } }'```

Comment: Try **ps faux** 
It should tell if there are any child processes to the one you are trying on. It might tell which one we need to kill.

Comment: HI, it produced a long list of PIDs but I did not see 127566. There are others though. What exactly would I look for in that list? The colnames from that command are ```USER        PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND```

Comment: Hang on, have I misundertood the screen shot above? the rows for each core show 100% under "sleeping" but I've just realized that "sleeping" is not a column header! Right? :-/

Comment: 'sleeping' not a header attribute.. That's correct!